# javascript is looping wrong when beginning is negative

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

Can anyone explain why my for loop even thpugh it iterates 30 times (-10+20 = 30 iterates), but when it comes to printing the innerHTML it begins with 10x undefined, and then it starts printing from -10 to 10 instead of -10 to 20?

The values of loop beginning and ending are defined in an external js script, with document.getElementByID, and gets returned later on. Maybe tihs can help. If i

```
 if (temperaturStart < 0){

            for(var i= temperaturStart; i<=  temperaturEnde; i++){
                temperaturArray.push(i* 9/5 + 32)
                var tbodyEL = document.querySelector("tbody");
                tbodyEL.innerHTML +=
                    `
                    <tr>
                        <td id="${tSpalte}">${temperaturArray[i]}</td>
                        <td id="${dichteSpalte}">${dataArrayDichte[i]}</td>
                        <td id="${DynVisSpalte}">${dataArrayDynVis[i]}</td>
                        <td id="${wärmeleitSpalte}">${dataArrayWärmeleit[i]}</td>
                        <td id="${stoffSpalte}">${stoff}</td>
                        <td id="${einheitSpalte}">${einheit}</td>
                    </tr> 
                    `
            }
```

[image: Example output if beginning of loop is -10, and end of loop is 20.]

Comment: Did you convert `temperaturStart` to a number after reading it from the document?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @ChrisG Yes i did.  The value is read from an html input. The input type itself is number, so it has to read it as an number. But just to be sure i also tried it out with parseInt(document.getElementByiID().value . But it still doesnt work,.

Comment: `type="number"` doesn't mean you'll get back a number from the `.value`. But adiga has found the obvious issue: you're accessing negative array indices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` is used for keeping track of range between `temperaturStart` and `temperaturEnde`. It can be negative. When you access negative index of all those arrays in `td`, it will return undefined. You need another variable `j` which starts at `0` to access the index of each of those arrays:

```js
// move this outside
var tbodyEL = document.querySelector("tbody");

for(var i= temperaturStart, j = 0; i <= temperaturEnde; i++, j++){
    temperaturArray.push(i* 9/5 + 32)

    tbodyEL.innerHTML +=
        `
        <tr>
            <td id="${tSpalte}">${temperaturArray[j]}</td>
            <td id="${dichteSpalte}">${dataArrayDichte[j]}</td>
            <td id="${DynVisSpalte}">${dataArrayDynVis[j]}</td>
            <td id="${wärmeleitSpalte}">${dataArrayWärmeleit[j]}</td>
            <td id="${stoffSpalte}">${stoff}</td>
            <td id="${einheitSpalte}">${einheit}</td>
        </tr> 
        `
}
```

---

It's unclear how `dataArrayDichte`, `dataArrayDynVis` and other arrays are populated. If they are populated inside the loop like `temperaturArray`, you can assign them to local variables:

```
var temperature = i * 9/5 + 32
```

And then use them directly in

```
<td id="${tSpalte}">${temperature}</td>
```

You wouldn't have to create the `j` variable or the arrays.

---

I'm assuming `tSpalte` is created inside the loop. Otherwise, multiple elements will have the same `id`s.